How to implement immediate in-app updates using Google Play API in Unity?
I'm trying to implement immediate in-app updates in my Unity game using the Google Play API, but I'm facing some issues. I want to use AppUpdateOptions.ImmediateAppUpdateOptions() for an immediate update without handling update priorities.
Here's the code I have so far:

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Google.Play.AppUpdate;
using Google.Play.Common;

public class InAppUpdateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;
    private AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfoResult;
    private AppUpdateOptions appUpdateOptions;

    private void Start()
    {
        appUpdateManager = new AppUpdateManager();
        StartCoroutine(CheckForImmediateUpdate());
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckForImmediateUpdate()
    {
        PlayAsyncOperation<AppUpdateInfo, AppUpdateErrorCode> appUpdateInfoOperation =
            appUpdateManager.GetAppUpdateInfo();

        yield return appUpdateInfoOperation;

        if (appUpdateInfoOperation.IsSuccessful)
        {
            appUpdateInfoResult = appUpdateInfoOperation.GetResult();

            if (appUpdateInfoResult.UpdateAvailability == UpdateAvailability.UpdateAvailable)
            {
                appUpdateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.ImmediateAppUpdateOptions();
                yield return StartImmediateUpdate();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to get app update info: {appUpdateInfoOperation.Error}");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartImmediateUpdate()
    {
        var startUpdateRequest = appUpdateManager.StartUpdate(appUpdateInfoResult, appUpdateOptions);
        yield return startUpdateRequest;

        if (startUpdateRequest.IsSuccessful)
        {
            Debug.Log("Update completed successfully. Restarting the app...");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Update failed: {startUpdateRequest.Error}");
        }
    }
}

However, I keep encountering an error:
Error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Google.Play.AppUpdate.AppUpdateType' to 'Google.Play.AppUpdate.AppUpdateOptions'

I’ve already checked the documentation, and it seems like I'm using the correct method for immediate updates. But I’m still not sure how to fix this error.

Is there something I’m missing in how I handle AppUpdateOptions or AppUpdateType?
Do I need to set up something differently for immediate updates using the Play Core API in Unity?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!
